# How to exclude specific file when downloading Clickonce?

Tags: visual-studio, winforms, clickonce

In Visual Studio, I publish the all files to url with Clickonce, its ok. But i don't want to download a specific file (for example app.config) when downloading from clickonce. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Project > Properties > Publish tab, Application Files button.

Comment: @HansPassant i checked but if i understand right then it exclude the file while publishing to server. I need exclude the file while downloading from server.

Comment: is there a solution friends?

Comment: @saittin, based on my research, I think it is hard for us to do it. Since you include the app.config, you can't exclude the file in the clickonce.

Comment: @JackJJun-MSFT thank you so much really for your effort.